# Default ControlTemplate for CheckBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I can't find the default WPF `ControlTemplate` for a `CheckBox`. Does anyone know how to locate it? All I can find is the [SilverLight default checkbox template on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278078%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

[MSDN has a custom control template for the WPF checkbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319.aspx) example which uses X's instead of check marks. I'm specifically looking for the default **check mark style** that comes standard with WPF - I just can't locate the XAML for it.

I've also [tried saving the template using `XamlWriter` to no avail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526435/175679). [Downloading the Simple Styles template from WPF Control Templates sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771597%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) also just uses the X's instead of classic check marks.

Comment: Do you have Expression Blend? If so it makes it much easier to interact with the Templates in general.

Comment: No - unfortunately I don't have access to Expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven's seen the default styles for any other theme but *Classic* available online but if you happend to find them, please post back here :) I think the templates over at MSDN are usually the *Classic* theme.

You can use Expression Blend to get it, you can download a [trial here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/).
Select the `CheckBox`, go to Object -> Edit Style -> Edit a Copy.

Assuming you are after the windows 7 (*aero*) style, here it is

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxFillNormal" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxStroke" Color="#8E8F8F"/>
<Style x:Key="EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CheckRadioFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxFillNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Awesome...you've saved me hours. I will have to remember the Blend trick for future reference.

Comment: Vs2012 also now includes "Edit a copy" too.

Comment: @AlSki Great suggestion - I do have VS 2012 and can [verify that **Edit Template -> Edit a Copy** has been added](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/22/example-winrtmetro-app-how-to-edit-default-template-in-visual-studio-2012-and-blend/). This rocks - no Expression license required! The output is the same as generated above via Expression. What a huge time savings just knowing the tools capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get all WPF controls control templates is to use this fantastic application : http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/2091

Comment: This is helpful, but it does not create a **template copy** as nicely as the feature does in Blend or VS 2012.

Comment: NEver tried Blend/VS2012 feature but I'll check ! Thanks for the input :)